# JSON return from a RESTful Query of TeamCity

Tags: json, teamcity

As per [Teamcity REST API](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin)

We can use the following to get XML Data

```
curl -v --basic --user USERNAME:PASSWORD --request POST "http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/users/" --data @data.xml --header "Content-Type: application/xml"
```

Can we do the same for JSON ?

```
 curl -v --basic --user USERNAME:PASSWORD --request POST "http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/users/" --data @data.json --header "Content-Type: application/json"
```

BOTH, return

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 05 Aug 2012 02:18:36 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: application/xml
```

Thus , Content-Type: xml

How can i get JSON Reponse.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to set the `Accept` header not the `Content-type` header

```
curl -v --basic --user USERNAME:PASSWORD --request POST "http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/users/" --data @data.json --header "Accept: application/json"
```

Comment: i get error:
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Length: 0
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
< HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
< Date: Sun, 05 Aug 2012 03:00:46 GMT
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-store
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=27DCA6F10D766DA21D5B3E0450CA58AD; Path=/teamcity/; HttpOnly
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
Error has occurred during request processing (Unsupported Media Type).
Error: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException

Comment: Changed POST , to GET and Got JSON , Thanks